# Sum of ideal sheaves commutes with taking global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $C, D$ effective divisors intersecting each other at finitely many points. Is it true that $$H^0((\mathcal{I}_C(d)+\mathcal{I}_D(d))/\mathcal{I}_X(d))=(I_d(C)+I_d(D))/I_d(X),$$ where $I_d(-)$ is the degree $d$th graded piece of the respective ideal?

Comment: Look into the $\Gamma_*(\bullet)$ construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large $d$ of course this is true. It may be false for small $d$. For example, take $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\subset\mathbb{P}^3$, the quadric hypersurface. Let $C,D$ be $\mathbb{P}^1\times \{p\},\mathbb{P}^1\times \{q\}$ for points $p\neq q$. You can see that for $d=0$, the map you describe is not onto.

Comment: The $d$ in my question is  not arbitrary, it is the same as the degree of the hypersurface. One can note that $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X(d))=0=H^1(\mathcal{I}_X(d))$. More generally, the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of $X$ is equal to $d$. In particular, I think this counterexample does not quite apply in my setting. May be I am wrong.

Comment: My example above can be modified for any $d$. For $d=2$, take distinct points $p_i,q_i, 1\leq i\leq 3$ and let $C$ be the union of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\{p_i\}$ and similarly $D$. Then for $d=2$, the map you describe is not onto.

Comment: If I assume that the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of $(\mathcal{I}_C(d)+\mathcal{I}_D(d))/\mathcal{I}_X(d)$ is zero and that of $C$ and $D$ are both at most $d$, is it sufficient to get a positive answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

(This is not *exactly* what you asked, but it's close to it.)

I'm going to start by stating a theorem about $\mathcal{O}$-modules on a projective variety, then I'll apply it to your case.

#### General Case

Let $X=\operatorname{Proj}(S)$, where $S$ is a graded algebra of finite type over a field $k$. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the irrelevant ideal. Given an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$, set
$$\Gamma_*(\mathcal{F}):= \bigoplus_{d\in \mathbb{Z}} \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}(d)). $$
This is naturally a graded $S$-module.

> **Theorem.** Let $M$ be any graded $S$-module, $\widetilde{M}$ the induced $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then there is a (natural) exact sequence of graded modules
>   $$0\to H^0_\mathfrak{m}(M)\to M\to\Gamma_*(\widetilde{M})\to H^1_\mathfrak{m}(M)\to0,$$
>   where the middle map is the natural one.

#### Your Case

For you, $S$ is the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$, and $M=S/(I(C)+I(D))$. Since $S/(I(C)+I(D))$ is a ring, I'll call it $R$ instead of $M$. Since $C\cap D$ is a complete intersection, it's also Cohen-Macaulay, and therefore so is its homogeneous coordinate ring. Therefore, the depth of $R$ (along its irrelevant ideal) is equal to the dimension of $R$, namely $1$. Hence, the first term in the above exact sequence vanishes. However, the third term *never* vanishes (or else the depth of $R$ would be at least $2$). In summary:

> If $C\cap D$ is finite and non-empty, then the natural map
>   $$ S/(I(C)+I(D)) \to \Gamma_*(\mathcal{O}_X/(\mathcal{I}_C+\mathcal{I}_D))$$
>   is injective but *not* surjective.

Comment: The point is exactly that. I am not asking the surjectivity that you write at the end. Rather I am asking that if the Castelnuovo Mumford regularity of the module is $d$ then is the degree $d$ graded pieces of the last morphism  surjective?